# Why do these triggers/events in this custom control working when it inherits from Control but not from Button?

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, triggers

These triggers work like expected when this custom control inherits from Control, but not when it inherits from button. When it inherits from button, the second trigger is never triggered. Also, when inherited from Button, the control will remain in the hovered state (i.e. first trigger is satisfied) if the mouse button remains held down, even if the cursor moves out of the control.

Snippet from Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ui:SquareButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundColorBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MainColorBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,2,2,0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ui:SquareButton}">
                <Border x:Name="PART_Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                    <Grid Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=AHeight}" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Height}">
                        <ui:ColorableImage x:Name="PART_Image" Source="calendar-black.png" Color="Black" Stretch="None"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SecondaryColorBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseLeftButtonDown" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainColorBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Color" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

SquareButton.cs:

```
public class SquareButton : Button
{
    static SquareButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SquareButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SquareButton)));
    }

    private static DependencyPropertyKey IsMouseLeftButtonDownPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("IsMouseLeftButtonDown", typeof(bool), typeof(SquareButton), , new PropertyMetadata());
    public static DependencyProperty IsMouseLeftButtonDownProperty = IsMouseLeftButtonDownPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    public bool IsMouseLeftButtonDown
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsMouseLeftButtonDownProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(IsMouseLeftButtonDownPropertyKey, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CornerRadius", typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(SquareButton));
    public CornerRadius CornerRadius
    {
        get { return (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        Border border = GetTemplateChild("PART_Border") as Border;
        if (border != null)
        {
            border.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Border_MouseLeftButtonDown);
            border.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Border_MouseLeftButtonUp);
            border.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(Border_MouseLeave);
        }
    }

    private void Border_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMouseLeftButtonDown = true;
    }

    private void Border_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMouseLeftButtonDown = false;
    }

    private void Border_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMouseLeftButtonDown = false;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use a trigger on the IsPressed property instead of your multitrigger ?

Comment: Looks like that works. Unfortunately, my button is spanning the entire width of the container... But that's another problem. Post that as the answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Yes, a button always take all the available space. You'll have to change the VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignment properties to change that.

Comment: Yep, I just figured that out. I tested it out with a normal Button, too, to see if the behavior is consistent with my control, and it is, so it's just a WPF thing. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a trigger on the IsPressed property instead of your multitrigger :

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainColorBrush}" />
    <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Color" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}" />
</Trigger>
```